# SVG paths not scaling

Tags: html, svg, resolution

I am using trying to use SVG for displaying a seating layout, where each seat is an individual `path`.

However, the svg does not seem to scale, that is the seats appear to be pixelating, and the sharpness of individual seat appears blurred.

On inspecting is seemed like it is because of the stroke not scaling, and I tried multiple attributes like `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;`
and `shape-rendering:crispEdges;` yet the seat looses the clarity, on smaller sizes.

The original svg is at http://jsbin.com/yepesi/2/ 
On a Smaller screen http://jsbin.com/yepesi/2/edit (thanks to JS bin panes)

I assumed that svgs would scale, I have no idea why this is happening.
I need help with any suggestions on how to keep the seats not pixelated and allow scaling.

Comment: The SVG seems fine to me.  It is scaling and shrinking as expected.  Can you explain what you mean by "pixelating"?  Obviously when details start getting smaller than a pixel, you are going to lose some sharpness. That's just physics.

Comment: What I mean by pixelating is that the seat strokes seem to overlap and do not appear linear as the screen shrinks. The clarity of each seat is lost as the svg scales down.

Comment: That's just the effects of antialiasing I'm afraid.  Once the widths of lines become just a fraction of a pixel, the browser is trying to simulate sub-pixel details by using grey pixels instead of black.  You can turn off antilising with crispEdges (as you've seen) but that will only look worse.  If you don't like the antialiasing effect, then probably your best solution is to simplify the shape of your seat to reduce the fine details.